# Contacts History for SMS Stopped Working

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-ace, chat-history

I noticed that when I go to Contacts > History, the last entry for SMS history is February. All text messages made from then on is no longer being logged in the History view. However, all call history seems to be fine.

I have searched my phone but couldn't find a setting to enable/disable the text message history logging. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Phone model: Samsung Galaxy Ace
Android version: 2.2.1

Update: It appears to be malfunctioning. I texted 8 different contacts today, it only logged 1.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by going to Contacts > Display Options > Select contacts to display > Check all